# Is it possible to add 24 hour date format date in PL/SQL ?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a **date** DataType Column as one of the column in my Table (Using PL/SQL Developer)
Requirement is to add a date in that column as '12-feb-2016 22:59:50'
Insert query in SQl ,to add date, and time in 24 hour format ?

Comment: Should be possible.

Comment: A `DATE` column does not have "a format" (and it is not stored with any specific format).  You can display it in any format you want.

Comment: Further to @a_horse_with_no_name, Oracle DATE data type includes time

Comment: you can use to_date('12-feb-2016 22:59:50'','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

Comment: PL/SQL Developer must be your front-end. It surely has the capability to process SQL statements. Is the requirement to use the graphical interface instead of a standard SQL `INSERT` statement? (If not, why do you have the directive **using PL/SQL Developer**?)

Comment: @ mathguy ,I want to display the date in graphical interface ,using insert statement (i.e ., What ever I inserted in DB ,should be displayed in Front end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible, use this query in insert statment:

`to_date('21-02-2006 14:06:14','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` keywords for constants:

```
TIMESTAMP '2006-02-12 22:59:50'
DATE '2006-02-12'
```

This comes from my general preference for ISO standard date/time formats.